# Achieve (format nil ...) with princ

Tags: common-lisp

Here's the behavior of a few format and princ calls:

```
(format nil "a")
"a"
CL-USER> 
(format t "a")
a
NIL
CL-USER> 
(princ "a" nil)
a
"a"
CL-USER> 
(princ "a" t)
a
"a"
CL-USER>
```

I would have thought that the `(princ "a" nil)` call would have returned "a", but not printed "a" to stdout, but it still prints "a" to stdout. Also I'm not sure why there's not a difference between the first and second princ calls.

I tried browsing the hyperspec, but I can't find the information I need.

I assume my misunderstanding is because `nil` and `t` are not streams, but format translates them to the return stream (whatever that is) and stdout. If that's the case, how can I get a `(format nil ...)` effect with `(princ ... ?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CL-USER 25 > (with-output-to-string (stream)
               (princ "a" stream))
"a"
```

Comment: Urggh; I was hoping there would be a way without with-output-to-string, but I guess not.

Comment: `princ-to-string` is one easy way. The whole NIL thing is because `princ` uses a [stream designator](http://l1sp.org/cl/glossary/stream_designator) and `format` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The function `FORMAT` is different from other output functions in that it accepts `NIL` to mean "return the output in a string instead of writing it". The general solution as suggested by Rainer is to use `WITH-OUTPUT-TO-STRING`.

Usually, there are special versions of the print functions that return the output as a string instead. In this particular case, what you want is the function `PRINC-TO-STRING` which does the same thing as `PRINC` but returns a string.